# Изменить value у input при изменении другого инпута

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Уже третий день пытаюсь решить эту задачу, уже начинаю сходить с ума.

Ситуация следующая:
У меня есть страница с формой, где я определил поля (буду писать упрощенный код, без всего лишнего):

```js
const companyForm = reactive({
  ogrn: null,
  inn: null,
})
```

Сами инпуты я сделал отдельным компонентом, куда передаю v-model и некоторые другие данные: (к слову, я использую библиотеку primevue, поэтому у меня в моем компоненте лежит компонент инпута от primevue, если это важно)

```html
<u-input-field
id="ogrn"
v-model="companyForm.ogrn"
/>

<u-input-field
id="inn"
v-model="companyForm.inn"
/>
```

В моем дочернем компоненте (u-input-field) я принимаю v-model от родителя и связываю родителя и ребенка с помощью следующих действий (к слову, подсмотрел по гайду как это все сделать, но сам до конца и не понял как работает emits):

```js
const emits = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const props = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const value = ref(props.modelValue)

watch(value, () => {
  emits('update:modelValue', value)
})
```

```html
        <input-number
          :input-id="props.id"
          v-model="value" />
```

Все это отлично работает.

Далее мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при изменении значения в одном инпуте, менялось значение и в другом самостоятельно.
Что я пробовал и как я думал это будет работать: (это я прописал в родителе, на странице формы)

```js
watch(
  () => companyForm.ogrn,
  (newValue) => {
    companyForm.inn = newValue
  }
)
```

Но это не работает, ну то есть не до конца. Само значение companyForm.inn действительно изменяется, если наблюдать его через девтулс, однако в самом инпуте это значение не отрисовывается, я не понимаю как вызвать ререндер компонента.

К чему я пришел по итогу методом тыка - добавить в компонент с инпутом еще один watch, чтобы он отслеживал изменения сверху у companyForm.inn. Вот так теперь выглядит код компонента:

```js
const emits = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const props = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const value = ref(props.modelValue)

watch(value, () => {
  emits('update:modelValue', value)
})

watch(
  () => props.modelValue,
  () => {
    emits('update:modelValue', value)
  }
)
```

```html
        <input-number
          :input-id="props.id"
          v-model="value" />
```

И это работает! Кроме самого первого изменения инпута ogrn... На первое изменение ничего не происходит, а на последующие уже второй инпут дублирует значение первого, как я и ожидаю.

Помогите пожалуйста понять что я делаю не так и как решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отслеживать изменение инпутов не в них самих, а в родительском компоненте.

Типа такого:

```typescript
const companyForm = reactive({
  ogrn: null,
  inn: null,
})


const INN = toRef(companyForm, "inn")

watch(INN, (val) => {
        companyForm.ogrn = val
      })
```

[Пример на Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqNkU9rhDAQxb/KkJNL7XoXXeilpZct7DmXoLEN5B9xtC3id+/EuFYPhSrIJM7v5b3JxJ68P4+DZCXjtkJpvBYoL9wCVK0aY8GRY6WsHxDGR+NaqWvOGme8sN/PLpizspazIjFFgoj4L+3ew4pT44pXxc4JLfsmKI/LCdwq411AmCBI0aAaZQ7obrLL4VNg8wEzdMEZ4IxicUoVGfm1MK3sxKCJ5baXOPjsFEugp3G2R/puvqDe9LO1ByB6LcEOWuf3LQp/2JlPe8HX65WEFnvZTjwnd8vUDs1vL7c/u9OUqD0BS9KM1HPIRqFPUF/uSaLacbp1Oq3kDB6Aun+NpirQKIKFacfN8c9MkeJLi6rYroDNP3h3vVc=)

---

UPD
Кастомный инпут:

```typescript
<template>
  <div>
        <input :id="id" :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import {defineProps} from "vue"

  const props = defineProps({
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Это не сработало в моем случае, потому что у Вас инпуты находятся прямо в родителе, а у меня инпуты внутри дочерних компонентов

Comment: @NDMX, я тестил на кастомных инпутах. Как бы предполагалось, что когда вы логику в родителя будете переносить, нужно будет еще и кастомные инпуты править. Добавил код кастомного инпута в пример.